# java - read context and rename

Tags: java, loops, rename

There are about 50 xml files in a folder.  I need to read through the content of each file and find context (example: year) and use that year in filename.

Also, i need to increment.
For example, if the context (year) found in 10 of those files is 2013, then the filenames should be 2013001, 2013002, 2013003, ..., 2013010.

Hope this is clear.
Thank you

Comment: Example to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recursively go through your directories and search each file for the date. After that you can simply rename the file and append the date as string.(The code might not work 100% because I don't have a IDE to test it at the moment.)

```
public void recursivelySearchFiles(String startPath) throws IOException {

     File root = new File(startPath);
     File[] list = root.listFiles();

     if (list == null) return;

     for ( File f : list ) {
         if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
             recursivelySearchFiles(f.getAbsolutePath());
         }
         else {
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
             String resultYear = "";
             String line;
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             resultYear = getSubStringFromString(line);

             }
             br.close();
             renameFile(f, resultYear);
             System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
         }
     }
 }

 public String getSubStringFromString(String line){
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
     if (matcher.find())
     {
         return matcher.group(1);
     }else{
         return "";
     }
 }

 public void renameFile(File oldfile, String year) throws IOException{
        String newPath = oldfile.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, oldfile.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("."));
        String ending = oldfile.getAbsolutePath().substring(oldfile.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".")-1, oldfile.getAbsolutePath().length());
        newPath += year;
        File file2 = new File(newPath + ending);
        if(file2.exists()) throw new java.io.IOException("file exists");

        boolean success = oldfile.renameTo(file2);
        if (!success) {
            System.out.println("renaming not successful");
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand at 100% but, you can go on the API of [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).
You have many usefull functions like :

- isDirectory : to know if the path is a directory.
- list : to list all entries of the directory
- lines : to create a    stream on a file (text file for you) and
  iterate over each line ; you can find your year here.
- move : move or rename a file to a target file.